# Why does Python swaps variable ids when swaps variables

Tags: python, swap, identify

I thought every object take an `id` based on key.

```
>>> a = 10
>>> b = 20
>>> id(a)
1876869280
>>> id(b)
1876869440
>>> a,b=b,a
>>> id(a)
1876869440
>>> id(b)
1876869280
```

When swap the variables, their ids are swapped too. If every object has a unique id, then why ids are swapped? I thought `id(a)` and `id(b)` will be same after swap.

Comment: What Ignacio said. You may find it helpful to read this article, written by SO member Ned Batchelder: [Facts and myths about Python names and values](http://nedbatchelder.com/text/names.html).

Comment: [a picture is worth a thousand words](http://python.net/~goodger/projects/pycon/2007/idiomatic/handout.html#other-languages-have-variables)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> If every object has a unique id, then why ids are swapped?

Because you swapped objects. The objects aren't `a` and `b`, they're `10` and `20`. `a` and `b` are just names that the code uses to refer to those objects.